# Performing test on a function which an Index error is expected from

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a class which i expect an index error from and i would like to test it.

I have tried the below, but does not seem to work:

```
input_data = []
my_class = StudentGrades()
result = my_class.calculate_score(input_data)
assert(IndexError, result)
```

I would appreciate any assistance on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using `pytest` since you tagged it.

Use [`pytest.raises`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions):

```py
with pytest.raises(IndexError):
    my_class.calculate_score(input_data)
```